# Save unexecuted network actions on android

Tags: android, networking, service, storage

I got a bit of a problem.

I have a running application for android which is great.
I use a "cleanservice" to store actions in a BlockingQueue which are then executed every minute the service is run.
Now the problem occurs when the user wants to close the app. When he wants to close I have the service run one last time to send all the actions over the internet.

But when no internet connection is available, all my queued actions are lost.

I need a way to store these actions (like in sharedpreferences or file or ...) when closing if they can't be send. And when I open the app again I can chekc if there are unexecuted actions that needs to be send.

I found [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) with several ways to store data. But what is the best way?

```
if(!finaltry)
                processActionQueues(true, true);
            else{
                // We get here when we are logging off (shutting down) and our final try has failed to send the updates to the server
                // We are going to save the actions so we can send them when we log on again

            }
```

My actions are from this interface:

```
public interface IWebServiceAction {
/**
 * Executes the action on the server.
 * Here you would typically do an http request to the webservice 
 * @param ctx
 * @return
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws AuthenticationException 
 */
boolean execute(Context ctx) throws IOException, AuthenticationException;
/**
 * Indicates whether this is an urgent action. If the action is
 * to be executed by the CleanService then it will execute it
 * immediately if the action is urgent.
 * Default = false
 * @return
 */
boolean isUrgent();
/**
 * If the user needs to be logged into the system before we can
 * execute the action then isPrivate is true.
 * Public actions that can be executed regardless of login are for
 * example the login action itself, or a check for updates.
 * Default = true
 * @return
 */
boolean isPrivate();

/**
 * Indicates whether this action requires that all previous actions are 
 * executed before we begin executing this one
 * @return
 */
boolean requiresQueueuToBeCompleted();
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up an SQLite database and keep track of your actions by that. That would make your queue obsolete and your action are always already stored in case the app gets force closed.

Or simply store them serialized (JSON?) to sharedpreferences.

Comment: I work with Json yes, so i'll give the sharedPreferences a try.